# 64-bit Eclipse and JVM

Tags: java

How do I tell if I am using 64-bit Eclipse and 64-bit JVM on my Linux machine?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: I'm using a software package that requires such constraints.

Answer (score 2):

To verify that you are using 64-bit JVM:

```
java -d64 -version
```

Comment: If I get the following error: "Running a 64-bit JVM is not supported on this platform.", does that mean I need to download a 64-bit JVM for Eclipse? Where is the link for this?

Comment: @syker, if you get that error - are you sure you are running a 64-bit version of Linux? You can't run 64-bit software on a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: How would I check? I'm pretty certain that I am runnning a 64-bit version of Linux though.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment above you say that you're using a software package that requires "such constraints". I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that, but for Java programs, it doesn't matter if the underlying Java implementation is 32-bit or 64-bit (well, as long as it doesn't need a huge amount of memory, for example). A normal Java program should run the same, no matter if it runs on a 32-bit or 64-bit OS.

`java -version` should give you an indication if your Java runtime environment is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Eclipse contains some native binaries (for the SWT libraries). Depending on if your Java runtime environment is 32-bit or 64-bit, you need a version of Eclipse with the corresponding native binaries. The [Eclipse download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) contains links for 32-bit and 64-bit Linux versions of Eclipse.

Note: If your OS is 64-bit but your Java RE is 32-bit, you will still need the 32-bit Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can tell from your eclipse.sh or your eclipse.ini if you are using 32bit or 64bit version, as the involved plugins are quite different.

As for the JVM, are you running Eclipse with something other than your default JVM? 'which java' usually tells you what you're using as your java executable.